# google drive api get all inserted hyperliks

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have to create a feature to share a **document** with some users. And sometimes there are hyperlinks to other files (all files belong to one user) in the shared "target file". And, I have to share these files with the "target user" too. So is there any way to get links or IDs of these files from the "target file"?

P.S. The **document** (target file) - is a file with mime *application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet* or mime *application/vnd.google-apps.document*

Comment: "Document" meaning - what? HTML? Word? Powerpoint? mp3 with a link stuck into the ID3 meta tags ...?

Comment: The Drive API doesn't contain anything to parse content from _within_ a file. Whether this is possible will depend on the type of document and the exact nature of the content.

Comment: @CBroe, I mean file, like word (mime: application/vnd.google-apps.document) or excel (mime: application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet)

Comment: Well those are google apps documents, they aren't word or excel files. But ok. So now you need to research those file formats I guess, unless anyone here has done the exact thing before.